# Is there any way to determine dog gender by face?

Tags: dogs

Here is two picture of the same Dog I got and I have asked to determine its gender.

[image: 2 Month Old]

[image: present]

Is there any possible way that logically determine its gender?

Comment: German Shepherd females have a distinct face than males, males tend to be longer, i usually can tell the gender of a GSD from its face.. but i dont know much

Comment: Very confusing. I usually guess. Maybe the way they pee can tell. If they sit then female if they stand then male.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell the gender of a dog?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26486/how-can-i-tell-the-gender-of-a-dog)

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this is possible.

People who know a specific breed inside out will know what to look for, in size and build, but this won't be 100% accurate. It will still be a guess, maybe an ever so slightly more accurate one, but a guess nonetheless. Not to mention there are always edge cases. It would be too inaccurate.

The only sure way is to check underneath and see what's there.

Answer (score 3):

Not that I know of. Even with humans, it's mostly possible because of fashion and hair cuts. Shave the heads (including beards) of random people and put them into identical wide clothes and you will have a hard time accurately determining their gender.

In the evolution of wolves and dogs, there was never a need to determine gender by looks. Dogs have their noses for that purpose.

There are some people claiming to determine a dog's gender by the overall build and gait, but this applies mostly to exceptional cases of certain breeds.

Comment: I don't mean to open a can of worms, but it is possible in humans: https://psychologyofbeauty.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/qt_movie.png